# Make pip always install binaries locally in virtualenv with --system-site-packages

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I'm using a virutalenv with `--system-site-packages` so that my builds don't take forever (I'm actually using Docker, so installs to the container environment are cached).

Problem is that `nose` is also getting installed to system site-packages. So when I later run `./myenv/bin/pip install --upgrade nose`, pip says "Requirement already up-to-date: nose in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages." As a result, the `nosetests` binary never appears in `myenv/bin`.

It's important that I should be able to reference that binary regardless of whether the system environment happens to have node installed. I have minor [moral qualms](https://gist.github.com/datagrok/2199506) with virtualenv's `activate`.

I assumed that pip's `--ignore-installed` flag would force the virtualenv-local install, but apparently I was wrong. It seems to force the reinstall the system-level package, still in system site-packages.

Comment: How does `--system-site-packages` make your Docker build faster?

Comment: Using more or less the last technique suggested in https://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/12/01/docker-python-pip-requirements/ . Docker image layer k is a system-level install of something that takes forever to build (e.g. scipy), k+1 is the step that copies my source into the container (which always invalidates the cache), step k+2 creates a virtualenv and installs to that virtualenv. The system-level installs get cached, so even though the virtualenv install step always happens, it can just use those system-level packages where possible.

Comment: A little more exactly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25307587/1464495

Comment: So create the virtualenv first, install scipy into it, add your requirements.txt, install those dependencies, and finally add the rest of your source.

Comment: Oy, dunno how I didn't think of that. Yes, that's the right thing to do here. Would you, SO power-user, recommend that I close this question or leave it open in case someone does end up actually needing the answer?