# Unable to install r package inside docker container

Tags: r, docker

I'm trying to install the docker package using binaries inside a docker container. inspired by this post:[How to speed up R packages installation in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51500385/how-to-speed-up-r-packages-installation-in-docker)

Now all the cran package to be installed is stored in file requirements-bin.txt

**Error:**

```
E: Unable to locate package r-cran-plumber
E: Unable to locate package r-cran-tolerance
```

**Docker File:**

```
FROM rocker/r-apt:bionic
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y libxml2-dev

# Install binaries (see https://datawookie.netlify.com/blog/2019/01/docker-images-for-r-r-base-versus-r-apt/)
COPY ./requirements-bin.txt .
RUN cat requirements-bin.txt | xargs apt-get install -y -qq


# Clean up package registry
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./src /app

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["Rscript", "Server.R"]
```

**requirements-bin.txt**

```
r-cran-plumber
r-cran-tolerance
```

Comment: could you please share the requirements-bin.txt file?

Comment: @hariK Added requirements-bin.txt in the Question

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue. At which stage it fails and where are you building this image?

Comment: @hariK it is failing at Step 5/11 : RUN cat requirements-bin.txt | xargs apt-get install -y -qq and I'm building this image on docker for windows

Comment: Works here too. Are you sure you don't have weird things like `\r\n` as new lines in your _requirements-bin.txt_ file since you are in Windows?