# How to install R packages in parallel way via docker?

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile, cran

I am installing several R packages from CRAN via docker file. Below is my docker file:

```
FROM r-base:4.0.2
RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get install -y --auto-remove \
      build-essential \
      libcurl4-openssl-dev \
      libpq-dev \
      libssl-dev \
      libxml2-dev \
      && R -e "system.time(install.packages(c('shiny', 'rmarkdown', 'Hmisc', 'rjson', 'caret','DBI', 'RPostgres','curl', 'httr', 'xml2', 'aws.s3'), repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/'))"
RUN mkdir /shinyapp
COPY . /shinyapp    
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/shinyapp/src/shiny', port = 5000, host = '0.0.0.0')"]
```

The docker build process is taking too much time (25 to 30 minutes). Below are the execution time details after completion of build.

```
user   system  elapsed 
1306.268  232.438 1361.374
```

Is there any way to optimize above Dockerfile? Any way to install packages in parallel manner?

**Note:** I have also tried `rocker/r-base`, but didn't find any luck in installation speed.

Comment: maybe useful; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51500385/how-to-speed-up-r-packages-installation-in-docker and this blog post and links therein http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2020/08/26/#029_introducing_bspm

Comment: if you install your packages using a separate command for each one, then installation progress gets cached and next time around you start at the line where changes began. You do not have to install all packages again that way.

Answer (score 4):

[‘pak’](https://github.com/r-lib/pak) performs package download and installation in parallel.

Unfortunately the [current CRAN version of ‘pak’](https://cran.r-project.org/package=pak) (0.1.2.1) is arguably broken: it has *tons* of dependencies. By contrast, the development version on GitHub has no external dependencies, as it should. So we need to install that one.

So you could change your Dockerfile as follows:

```
…
 && Rscript -e "install.packages('pak', repos = 'https://r-lib.github.io/p/pak/dev/'); pak::pkg_install(c('shiny', 'rmarkdown', 'Hmisc', 'rjson', 'caret','DBI', 'RPostgres','curl', 'httr', 'xml2', 'aws.s3'))"
…
```

But, frankly, that’s quite unreadable. A better approach would be to use `ARG` or `ENV` to supply the packages to be installed (this is regardless of whether we use ‘pak’ to install packages):

```
FROM r-base:4.0.2

ARG PKGS="shiny, rmarkdown, Hmisc, rjson, caret, DBI, RPostgres, curl, httr, xml2, aws.s3"

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y --auto-remove \
    build-essential \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libxml2-dev

RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("pak", repos = "https://r-lib.github.io/p/pak/dev/")' \
 && echo "$PKGS" \
  | Rscript -e 'pak::pkg_install(strsplit(readLines("stdin"), ", ?")[[1L]])'

RUN mkdir /shinyapp
COPY . /shinyapp

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["Rscript", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/shinyapp/src/shiny', port = 5000, host = '0.0.0.0')"]
```

Also note that R shouldn’t be invoked via the `R` binary for scripted use — that’s what `Rscript` is for. Amongst other things it handles stdout better.

Comment: Yes, the CRAN version of pak is broken and cannot install dependencies properly. The dev version on GitHub worked amazingly for me. It took 10 minutes less to complete the build. Thanks you!