# Using conda in Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, conda, miniconda

I am using conda-forge in my Dockerfile in order to install a ready environment from conda forge repository. To activate the environment, there are a lot of packages to be installed in the conda-forge command.

Problem is that this is happening every time when I re-build the Docker image.

Is there some possibility to cache it, and not reinstalling it again on every build process?

Critical part of code:

```
ADD https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN mkdir /root/.conda \
    && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b \
    && rm -f Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

RUN conda init bash
RUN conda create -c conda-forge --name arosics python=3
RUN conda install -c conda-forge 'arosics>=1.3.0'

RUN echo "conda init bash" >> $HOME/.bashrc
RUN echo "conda activate arosics" >> $HOME/.bashrc

SHELL ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/25305788/13875968

Comment: Yes, there is. If you'd shown us your Dockerfile, we might even be able to tell you how :)

Comment: I have added the critical part of Dockerfile to the question...Thanks